# Strange files after SciPy install & test

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, installation, scipy

I recently installed the SciPy library for python. At first it wasn't working because I did not have Blas installed. To correct the issue I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev
pip install scipy
```

This worked fine, and SciPy runs on my machine.I also ran nose test.However the directory where I ran this command now has many files as below. Does anyone know what these files are and if it is safe to move them to a different directory?

```
sc_06fa0fd248559689d6d193e00d4bf570e66d8bd2dc0f574eea568af167413f080.cpp
sc_06fa0fd248559689d6d193e00d4bf570e66d8bd2dc0f574eea568af167413f080.so
sc_118183af37296a78943145d3f2ebeffaf5e6165a905aeea0be561c34ad37982f0.cpp
sc_118183af37296a78943145d3f2ebeffaf5e6165a905aeea0be561c34ad37982f0.so
sc_118183af37296a78943145d3f2ebeffaf5e6165a905aeea0be561c34ad37982f1.cpp
sc_118183af37296a78943145d3f2ebeffaf5e6165a905aeea0be561c34ad37982f1.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files are generated by the `scipy.weave` test suite.  I've noticed that the test suite for `weave` can leave files in the directory where the tests were run.  It is safe to delete them.

Comment: Yep, I ran the nose test after install